# How can frontend application which is on reactjs call the django api?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I want to make a website on amazon aws ec2 Linux instances using reactjs as frontend and django rest framework as backend.

When i tested django API in postman tools its works but when django api call through reactjs as frontend it shows an error in preview of chrome "Cannot POST /api/v1/users/login/".

How make a connection between reactjs and django API?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and write a problem description. What are you doing? What programming language is this - add the relevant tag! For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)